# Is it possible to analytically compute maximum/minimum within an area for a 2D function defined in an area?

Tags: integration, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

For Easom function (or any other functions): $f(x,y)=\cos x*\cos y*\exp⁡\left(-(〖x-π)〗^2-(y〖-π)〗^2 \right)$, defined in a range $0\le x,y\le 10$, the plot will look as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39b43.png)

Is it possible to analytically compute maximum functional value within a circle of radius '$R$' (using double integral), which would be a subset of the original region.

Comment: For a general function I doubt there is an analytic form. For the specific function given the integral can probably be computed in terms of error functions, though it might get really messy.